# In FTIR, why is the sample interferogram out of phase with the background interferogram?

Tags: spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

I am reading "Fourier Transform Spectroscopy" by Griffiths and de Haseth. In section 2.4 Apodization they state:

[image]

1. I do not understand the physics behind why the sample interferogram is out of phase with the background interferogram.
2. I am a little confused as to the distinction between the interferogram of the source and that due to the sample. In my mind, once a sample is added it absorbs certain wavenumber and effectively removes those from the interferogram. Then the detector measures this "sample interferogram" i.e the source interferogram with certain wavenumbers removed, which is just a single interferogram. Griffiths and de Haseth seem to imply there is a separate sample interferogram. Is the Griffiths sample interferogram just the interferogram that consists of all wavenumbers that the sample removes?

Comment: When I model FTIR using optical calculus, as [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60031/41790), I do it like you suggest: there are two interferograms, one for the source only and the other for the sample plus source. Then processing of both interferograms takes place and apodization can be done on each interferogram separately. Good book, but I do not get what they were saying in the quoted section.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the link to your optical calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think about absorption of a wave is the emission of a destructively interfering wave. In a sense, this is what’s happening in your sample. Electrons are accelerated by the incident wave, causing them to emit another wave. If the incident wave is completely absorbed, that means the emitted wave is equal in frequency and amplitude, but 180$^\circ$ out of phase, with the incident wave.